# singular value decomposition and low rank tensorial approximation

Tags: matlab, matrix, approximation

according this article

http://www.wseas.us/e-library/conferences/2012/Vouliagmeni/MMAS/MMAS-07.pdf

matrix can be approximated by one rank   matrices using  tensorial  approximation,i know that in matlab  kronecker product plays  same role as  tensorial  product,function is  kron,now let us suppose that we have following matrix

```
a=[2 1 3;4 3 5]

a =

     2     1     3
     4     3     5
```

SVD of this matrix is

```
[U E V]=svd(a)

U =

   -0.4641   -0.8858
   -0.8858    0.4641


E =

    7.9764         0         0
         0    0.6142         0


V =

   -0.5606    0.1382   -0.8165
   -0.3913    0.8247    0.4082
   -0.7298   -0.5484    0.4082
```

please help me  to  implement algorithm with using tensorial approximation reconstructs original matrix in matlab languages,how can i  apply  tensorial product?like this

```
X=kron(U(:,1),V(:,1));
```

or?thanks in advance

Comment: If all you want is to do it for order-2 tensor, all you need is the outer product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about the Tensorial interpretation but the closest rank-1 approximation to the matrix is essentially the outer-product of the two dominant singular vectors amplified by the singular value.

In simple words, if `[U E V] = svd(X)`, then the closest rank-1 approximation to `X` is the outer-product of the first singular vectors multiplied by the first singular value.

In MATLAB, you could do this as:

```
U(:,1)*E(1,1)*V(:,1)'
```

Which yields:

```
ans =

    2.0752    1.4487    2.7017
    3.9606    2.7649    5.1563
```

---

Also, mathematically speaking, the kronecker product of a row vector and a column vector is essentially their outer product. So, you could do the same thing using Kronecker products as:

```
(kron(U(:,1)',V(:,1))*E(1,1))'
```

Which yields the same answer.